# ui-select inside of accordion

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, ui-select2

Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/17ime385yybvlCXWBsTX?p=preview

Accordion tab overlaps the ui-select (not ui-select2) search result. I have recreated the problem in the plunkr. I tried tweaking css with z-index but doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.accordion-body.in { overflow:visible; }
```

The above css code was all needed. Apparently the problem was with the bootstrap accordion and not the ui-select.

Answer (score 0):

`div` with class "select2-drop select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" has position `absolute`. If you change it to `relative` or `inherit`, it will appear.

Comment: Even though the result does appear by changing the position from absolute to relative but by doing so it also increases the height of the tab while displaying the result.